# What is the role that setuptools has evolved to? What does backend support mean?

Tags: python, setuptools

I recently took a course on Python packaging that covered `setuptools` and `setup.py`. I then went to the library's [documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html) and I found out that I was taught old stuff due to the move to `setup.cfg` and other new changes :(

Besides the way in which `setuptools` has modernised, I was interested to read in the [Python packaging at a glance section](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html#python-packaging-at-a-glance) the following:

> The landscape of Python packaging is shifting and Setuptools has evolved to only provide backend support, no longer being the de-facto packaging tool in the market.

**Q**: First of all, what do they mean by backend support? And then, what does the the current landscape look like, and what are the (frontend, I guess, but again what is this) alternatives to `setuptools`?

Looking a bit [more](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/index.html#transition-to-pep517) I also found:

> Since setuptools no longer serves as the default build tool [...]

But then a google search led me to the [recommended tools](https://packaging.python.org/guides/tool-recommendations/#packaging-tool-recommendations) of the Python Packaging authority, and in there it says:

> - Use setuptools to define projects and create Source Distributions.
> - Use the bdist_wheel setuptools extension available from the wheel project to create wheels. This is especially beneficial, if your
>   project contains binary extensions.

**Q**: Does that mean that the result of the evolution of the landscape has led to `wheel`?

Comment: For packaing I find the functionality of python poetry https://python-poetry.org/docs/ to be excellent, however there has been some issues latetly with it taking a long time to resolve package dependencies that the community behind it are grappling with.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1987/